# Is there a way to seek through a file without loading the whole thing into an array?

Tags: ruby

This works:

```
f = File.new("myfile").readlines
f[0] #=> "line 1"
f[21] #=> "line 22"
```

But what if I have a very large file, and only need to read a few lines. Is it possible to seek to specific lines and read them in Ruby, without loading the file into an array?

I grok IO streams, where (as in the case of stdin) you can't randomly seek through a stream. Surely there must be a way to do this without loading the entire file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purpose you can use the `each_line` iterator, combined with `with_index` to have the line number of the current line (counting from 0):

```
File.open('myfile') do |file|

  file.each_line.with_index do |line, lineno|
    case lineno
    when 0
      # line 1
    when 21
      # line 22
    end   
  end

end
```

By using `open`, passing a block to it, instead of `new`, you are guaranteed that the file is properly closed at the end of the block execution.

**Update** The `with_index` method accepts an optional argument to specify the starting index to use, so che code above could be better written like this:

```
file.each_line.with_index(1) do |line, lineno|
  case lineno
  when 1
    # line 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't ignore the `IO` class.  `IO::foreach` is one of those methods that returns an Enumerator, and can be lazily evaluated.

`IO#each_line` is also another one that will return an Enumerator.

In Ruby 2.0 we can call `.lazy` and use those methods, except for zip and cycle, that allow us to traverse the enumeration without bringing the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Jack and toro2k's answers (roughly the same answer), but modified it for my own use case. Where I may want to: open a file, and seek multiple random lines, where the order may not always be sequential. This is what I came up with (abstracted):

```
class LazyFile
    def initialize(file)
        @content = File.new(file)
    end

    def [](lineno)
        @content.rewind if @content.lineno > lineno
        skip = lineno - @content.lineno
        skip.times { @content.readline }
        @content.readline
    end
end

file = LazyFile("myfile")
file[1001]
```