# Editing a giant file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an 86MB CSV that I am trying to parse in order to reduce its size, but my code isnt working. When I change the input file to another file it works perfectly. Am I missing something obvious?

```
arr=Array.new
File.open('regressionModels.csv').each{|x|
puts x #for testing only
if(!(x.include?"NA"))
    arr.push(x)
end 
}
File.open('regressionModelsCleaned.csv','w').puts arr.join("\n")
```

EDIT: added this line to make sure the file exists:

```
puts File.file?('regressionModels.csv')
```

NOTE: I am trying to use the array because I am trying to write to my SSD less.

Comment: Have you tried to use the built-in csv functions instead of manually opening the files? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Yep, just tried it.....still no result

Comment: then you should try to parse your CSV lazily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729618/is-there-a-way-to-seek-through-a-file-without-loading-the-whole-thing-into-an-ar

Comment: This question needs to be reduced down in scope quite a bit.  Especially the "is this optimized" part, which sounds like textbook "Too Broad" territory

Comment: Ditch the array and write to regressionModelsCleaned.csv line by line. Won't be much faster but you'll be able to see progress and save memory.

Comment: I agree, but I hate to write to an SSD 800K times. Shouldn't I see progress with the puts x statement printing to console anyway?

Comment: don't puts anything 800K times - that is very slow by itself

Comment: true, but right now nothing is happening.... its like the foreach loop is being skipped, but no error if I throw it in a begin-rescue

Answer (score 0):

Using lazy enumeration might help your problem. You might do something like:

```
File.open('clean.csv', 'w') do |clean|
  File.open('dirty.csv').lazy.each do |dirty|
    clean.write(dirty) unless dirty.include? "NA"
  end
end
```

There is also no need to build up a intermediate array (which might also be contributing to your problem). You can open both files then write from the new one as you loop over the old one.

Comment: I just tried it, no luck- it is like the foreach loop is being skipped, yet I know the file exists

Comment: By no luck what do you mean? I ran this against a 2.5GB file with no issues

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't need to guard against substring hits, I'd use something like:

```
File.open('regressionModelsCleaned.csv', 'w') do |file_out|
  File.foreach('regressionModels.csv') do |csv_line|
    file_out.puts csv_line if csv_line['NA']
  end
end
```

I wouldn't worry about aggregating the matching lines into an array. A SSD has a MTBF well beyond the point where you'll be using the drive. Consider how often an OS writes to the device in a second; Your code is just a drop in the bucket.